# Migration installer error on pimcore 10.6v

Tags: php, symfony, pimcore

in my existing bundle, im getting this error in pimcore 10.6 version migration installer error,
[image]

this installer not able find out it in vendor as its using in earlier version, in the current version its not using, so can anyone know which will be the alternative method to use instead of this?

pimcore demo its not used, none of the pimcore doc its given about migration installer, not able to find the solution

If anyone come across this error or know about this? please let me know